# How to Pass a List of Strings in a ASP.net Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom server control in my ASP.net Application:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Stellt Funktionen zur Verfügung um eine Liste aus Controls auf der .aspx Seite zu erstellen.
    /// </summary>
    [PersistChildren(false)]
    [ParseChildren(true)]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:ControlCollection runat=server></{0}:ControlCollection>")]
    public class ControlListAction : Control
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Die IDs der Controls der Liste.
        /// </summary>
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public List<string> ControlIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Control in the .aspx file.

```
        <cc2:ControlListAction ID="enableControlsExceptThis" runat="server">
            <ControlIDs>
                <Item>itbMail</Item>
                <Item>txtNotizen</Item>
            </ControlIDs>
        </cc2:ControlListAction>
```

How i have to write that the code i wrote works? Or is another solotion the best?

Comment: As soon as your **prop** named `ControlIDs` type `List<string>` gets data soon after bind it to `enableControlsExceptThis` e.g. `enableControlsExceptThis.DataSource = ControlIDs ` and then call `databind()` method. Have you tried something like this?

Comment: Yes i think this is possible, but it have to be on the .aspx file because our customers want to change by themselve wich Control should be enabled!

Comment: If i do this with list of objects like a "Mail" object it would works.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to use a String[] Property with the StringArrayConverter Attribute. Then you can pass the Strings "," Seperated.